# Golang TLS test where server and client negociate the same keys at every execution to facilitate debugging

Tags: go, tls1.2, tls1.3

I have a test case for a golang project that uses crypto/tls to start a TLS client and a server. My test accesses the ciphertexts exchanged by the client and server to run assertions.

I'm looking for a way to get the same ciphertexts across consecutive executions of the test.

The values of the negotiated keys and the plaintext returned by the server are not relevant to the test.

Comment: Untested! [`tls.Config`](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/tls#Config) has `Rand` field. Replace it with  a reader that `Read` the  same byte all the time. Then each time  the client and  the server echange the keys, they should generate the same keys.

Comment: I have tried that but it unfortunately produces the different ciphertexts. From the docs: `Rand provides the source of entropy for nonces and RSA blinding` Does that yield the same ciphertexts?

Comment: @alexandru.topliceanu, could you please give us more details of your test codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test sample of [tls sample](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/crypto/tls/example_test.go#L98) could help you, define one `zeroSource` implemented `Read` interface for `Rand` of `tls.config`.

```golang
type zeroSource struct{}

func (zeroSource) Read(b []byte) (n int, err error) {
    for i := range b {
        b[i] = 0
    }
    // assign the same key to b

    return len(b), nil
}

// server side
    server.TLS = &tls.Config{
        Rand: zeroSource{}, // for example only; don't do this.
    }

// client side
    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
                Rand:               zeroSource{}, // for reproducible output; don't do this.
            },
        },
    }
```

Comment: Have you tested this? I have and it produces different ciphertexts!

Comment: @alexandru.topliceanu, I just run the tls sample code, it seems ok, Is there anything am I missing?

Comment: @alexandru.topliceanu, just confirm the sample code could generate same CLIENT_HANDSHAKE_TRAFFIC_SECRET and SERVER_HANDSHAKE_TRAFFIC_SECRET under tls1.3. the cipher text could be same. Is there anything am I missing?

Comment: Hmm, I didn't try the certificate from the TLS tests. I only tried the zero source and it didn't work. I'll give it a try and come back.